# Laravel Unique validation for one record

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have a table table for providers in that i have to save provider id, code_id and rate. Here multiple providers have multiple code_id and provider have one code_id as unique, if he wants to save that code again validator has to say this provider has already this code id like that.

Here i want save values like below

```
**id     provider_id      code_id     rate**
   1           2            2         11.23 ....yes
   2           3            2         25.56 ....yes
   3           2            2         25.36 ....no
   4           5            3         25.56 ....yes
   5           5            3         25.56 ....no
```

How can add a validation for this.

Here is my code i have tried.

```
 $addProviderCptCodeRules = array(
            'provider_id'=>'required',
            'code_id'=>'required|table_name,provider,code_id,'.$input['code_id'],
            'rate'=>'required',
        );
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

use [unique_with](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) validation

```html
 $addProviderCptCodeRules = array(
            'provider_id'=>'required',
            'code_id'=>'required|unique_with:code_id,provider_id,
            'rate'=>'required',
        );
```

Comment: with this validation also we can't save other provider with the same code id

Comment: before that you need to use this "felixkiss/uniquewith-validator:1.*" and update your composer

Comment: if i want to do it in update, in that case how can i do?